# SQL - get rows where one column is a certain percentage greater than another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get rows where one column is a certain percentage greater than another.

So say I have 2 columns:

- `InventoryLevel int`
- `InventoryAlert int`

I need to get all rows where the `InventoryLevel` is 25% greater than the `InventoryAlert`.

Is that possible to do all in one query? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT InventoryLevel,
       InventoryAlert  
FROM YourTable
WHERE InventoryLevel > 1.25 * InventoryAlert 
/*Incorrect for stated question but meets clarification in comment 
  "InventoryLevel is any value greater than 25%, doesn't have to be exact. "*/
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the great answer (and the psychic powers) ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE InventoryLevel = 1.25*InventoryAlert -- Or Maybe >= ?
```

Comment: +1 The question does actually say "25% greater" not "greater than 25% greater" as my answer seemed to assume!

Comment: @Martin Smith - Yeah, I didn't know if it should be **exactly** 25% greater, or more than 25% greater

Comment: Nice! Going to give this a shot. It's if InventoryLevel is any value greater than 25%, doesn't have to be exact.

Comment: @jyoseph - Oh in that case I'll undelete my answer then as I must have psychic-ly known that was the requirement.

Comment: @Martin Smith - yeah, you should let your answer There. Though I have to admit that is unfair for you to have so much knowledge on SQL and psychic powers